# mySQL selecting records due within the next month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select all records in a table which have a date between the current date and 1 month ahead.

The date is stored like this DD-MM-YYYY

And the query I have tried:

```
SELECT * from tablename WHERE renewalDate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) AND  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

But this does not return the correct results.

Comment: Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` please. We need to know the column type and index (if any).

Comment: are you saying your dates are stored as strings? do they have to be?

Comment: Also, you have an error in the second portion of your query, it should be DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) to be consistent with the first argument of you between

Answer (score 0):

Is the date stored in an actual date or datetime field? If it's in a char/varchar field, you won't be able to use the BETWEEN syntax, as mysql will just treat them as fixed strings.