# Using PHP & cron how can i inform  a user that he has got 15 days more left to pay his amount?

Tags: php, mysql

**DueDate Table structure**

[image]

my query here is **how to check automatically in php that a user has 15 days prior** from the table and inform a user that he has got 15 days more left to pay his amount.
15 days from the dueDate as shown in the table

so if the user due date is `2011-11-17` he has to be informed 15 day prior that is on `2011-11-02`

how to achieve this using php to inform automatically ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL selecting records due within the next month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663237/mysql-selecting-records-due-within-the-next-month) and countless more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+mysql+date+due&submit=search

Comment: @hakre not a duplicate one? my query is different than that question

Comment: You mean you choose other words and some other amount of days?

Comment: my query here is how to check automatically in php that a user has 15 days prior from the table

Comment: I think it'll be awhile before 2011-77-02 rolls around, so your customers don't have much to fear. ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a script run by [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) scheduled daily, probably on 00:01am every day.

You have to create a cron tab file, a plain text file and load it on your server. A cron tab file look like this

1 0 * * * php /path/to/your/script.php

Above file will run script.php on 00:01 am daily.

Reference/tutorial: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

In script.php, you do the 15 days look-up thingy.

Details...

There should be a CRON editor on your server's cpanel. You might not even need to write your own cron tab file, they usually have a GUI editor. If not `1 0 * * * php /path/to/your/script.php` is your only content.

`1 0 * * *` means run the following command every day at 00:01am.
`php` means execute the following PHP file and
`/path/to/your/script.php` specifies which PHP file to run.

Remember that path mush be absolute path starting from the root of your server because CRON is not the same as running on web environment.

On script.php, you do the query (see other answers), get the list of people who are 15 days away from their due date and do the notification.

You can test your script.php by running directly from web browser before putting it into cron too.

Comment: how to use CRON in php ? where exactly should i run this function

Comment: what cron tab file should be loaded to the server and what is the content of it? and where should i use my function for informing the user

Comment: @soul The OP has provided a link to information about cron. I suggest you go and read up on it and if you have any further specific questions come back (although those questions may be more suited to ServerFault).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [date time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions of mysql.

```
SELECT instalmentsDetailsID 
FROM DueDate 
WHERE DATE_SUB(dueDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY) >= NOW()
```

Comment: If those are text fields, string functions would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM DueDate WHERE DATE_ADD(DueDate , INTERVAL -15 DAY) <= NOW()
```

That will give you all the items that are currently in their notice period

Comment: This will give you anything due in 15 days or longer. Also why use DATE_ADD with a negative rather than DATE_SUB?

Comment: @liquorvicar: Thanks. I get the >= <=  wrong all the time with dates, so I normally test. And I didn't know about date-sub until just now :)